# combine flags with wildcards using RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to understand some basic rewrite stuff, so what I fount is something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www2.example.de|example.de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if I combine it like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www2.example|example).(.+)$ [NC]
```

I get an internal server error because of too many redirects.

So how can I combine with or whithout www and with different domain endings:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.name$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.name$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think it should be quite simple but I just don't get it...

Comment: "Combine" them to do what? Please explain what you want to achieve with mod_rewrite?

Comment: The first cond redirects example.anything to www.example.com and the second cond redirects www2.example.de or example.de to www.example.com, now I want something like ('www'|'').example.(*) to be directed to www.example.com.

Comment: Or maybe easier: in my last code block I have 5 RewriteCond and would like to do the same in 1 RewriteCond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The five coditions could be combined in a single one, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$               [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?example\.(name|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I do it like this I get the same: error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) .. any other idea?

Comment: My mistake. I included `www.example.com'. Added one line to my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, now I finally understood the too-many-redirects error... !